# Finding hourly mean over multiple dataset

Tags: dataset, netcdf, python-xarray, pandas-resample, era5

I want to take the hourly mean of t2m values after loading multiple .nc files, loaded using `xr.open_mfdataset`, but after resampling and taking the mean gives incorrect time dimensions.

I have loaded multiple .nc files using

```
ds =xr.open_mfdataset("../t2m/*.nc", concat_dim="time", parallel = True)
```

which has hourly data from 1-1-1979 to 31-12-2019.
I wanted to choose the only the month of May and I used

```
dm = ds.isel(time=(ds.time.dt.month == 5))
```

I want to take the hourly mean so used the resampling as `.resample(time='1D')` which grouped them into 1271 groups, which is correct (since 41years*31days of May = 1271)
But when I used `.mean(dim="time")` it is giving the time dimension as

> Dimensions: time: 14641

14641 is the number of hours from 01-05-1979 to 31-05-1979 including all the months in between, so it is considering all the hours between these two dates irrespective of month.

[Image shows resampling operation giving 1271 groups but when followed by mean, it gives 14641 dimensions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLQ40.jpg)

After taking the mean the dimension should have been 1271.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show your code and paste the dataset (`print(ds)`) at key points where you’re seeing the issue?

Comment: I think the resample here is the wrong thing to do. I do not know what @Yash_U is trying to achieve, but resample the `dm` like this, means you just start the new data from 1979-05-01 with daily step to 2019-05-31, meaning you will get 14641 datapoints (and a lot of missing values actually).

Comment: Actually, just checked, you can do daily means for May using resample, but use dropna in the end to get rid of missing data: actually, you can use resample, but then append `dropna` in the end:
`dout = ds.isel(time=(ds.time.dt.month == 5)).resample(time='D').mean(dim="time").dropna(dim='time')`

Comment: I have edited the question for better clarity and what I understand is going on. I have included the image as well.

Comment: @msi_gerva, your line of code is working but it is not working if I try to subset the data for a region and apply the regionmask and then use your line of code. `dout = ds.isel(time=(ds.time.dt.month == 5), drop = True).sel(longitude=slice(65,90),latitude = slice(35,8)).where(land_mask == 0).resample(time='D').mean(dim="time").dropna(dim='time')
`, where `land_mask` from `regionmask`, just assigns the `nan` value to the sea region. I don't see a reason for not working.

Comment: @msi_gerva's suggestion seems to solve the problem. This masking problem sounds like a separate issue which is better not dealt with in the comments