# Hourly mean after resampling and subsetting the dataset

Tags: pandas, netcdf, python-xarray, pandas-resample, era5

I have multiple .nc files that I combined using `xr.open_mfdataset`, floowed by subsetting it for study region and applying the mask using `regionmask` and resampled it to take hourly mean, but it is giving wrong answer.

```
ds =xr.open_mfdataset("../t2m/*.nc")
```

has houly data from 01-01-1979 to 31-12-2019 and gives Dimensions: longitude: 1440 latitude: 721 time: 359400.
After subsetiing for only month of May each year and for only study region using

```
dm = ds.isel(time=(ds.time.dt.month == 5)).sel(longitude=slice(65,90),latitude = slice(35,8)).where(land_mask == 0)
```

gives Dimensions: longitude: 101 latitude: 109 time: 30504 and land_mask uses masking of ocean datapoints using `regionmask`.

Now taking the

```
dout = dm.resample(time='D').mean(dim="time").dropna(dim='time')
```

Gives dimension as Dimensions: time: 0 latitude: 109 longitude: 101
The output should have been time:1271 i.e. number of days in all the 41 May that comes in between the dataset.(41*31=1271).
I dont get any reason why the time dimension is null instead of 1271.
NOTE: If I skip isel,sel and regionmask operation this works out fine.(see [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74311873/finding-hourly-mean-over-multiple-dataset)

I cant come up with a reason here.

Answer (score 0):

See the [`.dropna`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.dropna.html) docs:

> **dim** (`Hashable`) – Dimension along which to drop missing values. Dropping along multiple dimensions simultaneously is not yet supported.
>
> **how** (`{"any", "all"}`, *default*: `"any"`) –
>
> - any : if any NA values are present, drop that label
> - all : if all values are NA, drop that label

Using `.dropna(dim="time")` with a spatially masked dataset will always drop all time points. If you want to only drop observations in which all pixels are nan, use `how='all'`